# Android popup black screen

Tags: android, kotlin, popup

I am very new to android development, and am trying to have a button open a new screen as a sort of popup. However, when the button is pressed, an all black screen is opened. This happens even though my .xml resource file that I am opening is not a black screen. I followed a tutorial for the code, so I am not 100% sure of it all.

Here is the code that the button activates:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.popup_language)

    var langDM = DisplayMetrics()
    var width = langDM.widthPixels
    var height = langDM.heightPixels

    getWindow().setLayout((width*.8).toInt(), (height*.8).toInt())
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to have the popup take up less than the full screen. The black screen that comes up is the entire screen.

Let me know if I need to give more info on the .xml or can clarify anything else. Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're instantiating a new DisplayMetrics.  That's not what you want, you want to get the current display metrics.  Try  `getResources().getDisplayMetrics();`

Comment: Thanks so much, looks like that's what the problem was! I appreciate the help